# Aviod duplicate items in datasource bind checked list box in vb

Tags: vb.net

I made program for populating the data in checked list box. But  the  problem is the repeated names are displayed in checkedlist box. My code is given below. How can I avoid the duplicate names in `checkelstbox` using this databind property?

```
Dim str = "select distinct t.vc_doctype ***********"

    conobj.readdata1(str)
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = conobj.ds.Tables(0)
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "vc_doctype"
    CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "vc_doctype"
```

Comment: Did you check the data returned by sql?

Comment: thaks for the reply.without query chek how to do dis

Comment: you have to make sure the datasource doesnt have duplicate entries.
check the result of your query ""select distinct t.vc_doctype ***********""

Comment: sir there is mainly 2 checkedlist box.the 2nd one is populated based on the first one.the popultion is done successfuly,but the problem is when selecting the other items in the chedlstbx1 they also contain the same items that are also populated to the 2nd.i need to avoid this duplication in 2nd checkedlistbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to check your query, you can get whatever result to a datatable and in your code you can get the distinct values to a new Datatable.

For the code above you can follow something like this

```
Dim view As New DataView(conobj.ds.Tables(0))
Dim DistinctValues As New DataTable
DistinctValues = view.ToTable(True, "vc_doctype")
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = DistinctValues
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "vc_doctype"
CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "vc_doctype"
```